# How to force bundler to re-fetch tag ref from GitHub

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a gem that I manage, and have recently updated the ref for a tag (the SHA for the tag is now different on GitHub)

In my Gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'my_gem', tag: '0.25.0', git: 'http://github.com/Example/my_gem.git'
```

However, running `$ bundle install` only uses the old SHA for that tag. How can I force it to get the latest code?

I tried removing the path to my gem, like so:
    $ rm -rf /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/bundler/gems/my_gem-*

... but bundler just downloads it again.

The only way I've been able to make this happen is by modifying the revision in my `Gemfile.lock`, but that only works on that one repo. I have multiple repos using this gem. It seems like Bundler has a database/cache mapping gem tags to revisions, but I can't find where that is.

PS: I know re-tagging things isn't best practice.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line from your `Gemfile`, run `bundle install` and then `bundle clean --force` (this will remove any unused/old versions of gems), then add the gem again to your Gemfile and run `bundle install` again?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly, it still uses an old SHA. I believe it pulled it down again, but bundler is still getting the SHA first associated with the tag.

Comment: Too bad :-( On the bright side, it's good to know that Bundler safeguards against this kind of retagging, as it has all kinds of potential for malicious use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `bundle update my_gem`

ref: https://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-update.1.html